# C++ define

Tags: c++

Как правильно написать вторую строчку, что бы код заработал?

```
#define A "name"
int A;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Убрать кавычки в `define`.

P.S. Не знаю, зачем вам это, но лучше так не делать.

Comment: Ну, иногда это простейший способ переопределить функцию.

Comment: Я хотел. #define A a;  #define B A##"b"; int B; Блин, а действительно убрать кавычки. ))

Comment: @avp миниэвм 70х остались только в музеях. На кой ляд эти анахронизмы?

Comment: я думаю, `#define A name` отличный аналог `#define true false`. Парочка таких define, заботливо разбросанных по файлах могут сделать отладку веселым занятием.

Comment: @alexlz А чем сейчас пользуются, когда нужно, вот как у меня получить новую переменную путем сложения двух?

@KoVadim Я же упростил, держите полный пример #define PROJECTNAME "projectname"; #define PROJECTVER PROJECTNAME ## "_versions"; Versions PROJECTVER[]={};

Comment: @alexlz, просто иногда учень удобно написать в .h что-то вроде

     #ifdef TEST22
     #define syslog my_syslog
     #endif // TEST22

Comment: @avp, мне так больше по душе :)

    void my_syslog(/**/)
    {
    #ifdef TEST22
    //
    #else
    //
    #endif
    }

Comment: @klopp, тогда у Вас всюду в коде должен вызываться `my_syslog`, а что делать, если там в 10-ке .c файлов вызывается именно `syslog()`?

Проще добавить (или поправить подходящий) .h, и в Makefile доавить к CFLAGS -DTEST22

Comment: @avp, прилинковать свою функцию syslog. Хотя, конечно, извращение всё это: в своих исходниках изначально везде my_syslog должен быть, а переопределять его для чужих - нафиг надо...

Comment: @klopp, ну, не даром же всюду TEST22 прописано...  (именно syslog это просто для примера).

Это все для удобства экспресс отладки.

Comment: Я об этом:

    #ifdef TEST22
    void syslog(int p, const char *f, ...) { my_syslog( p, f ); }
    #endif